# Connect router to another router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

I recently bought a router (TP-Link Archer C6) which worked great at covering my entire apartment. My ISP recently upgraded to fiber, so they provided me with their own router. Problem is, this router doesn't have a good enough range. I get a very weak signal outside the room where the router is placed. I think I might be able to use my C6 to solve this problem. I was thinking of connecting an ethernet cable from one of the LAN ports on ISP router to WAN port of my Archer C6. Would this work? I would like to know how to configure C6 in order to achieve this?

Note: I'm not looking at extending the range, since these routers will basically be kept next to each other. I'll keep a different SSID for Archer C6 and have all devices connect to that instead.

I have seen a lot of questions about connecting router to another router, but not in the way I want to do it, hence creating this new question.

Comment: Both cascading and bridging have been covered alot here. Which one are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Looking at the answer from Charles below, looks like I should try LAN to LAN. I'm not sure if this method is called cascading or bridging.

Comment: It's called bridging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would work but in my opinion it would be easier to use a LAN port on your Archer C6.  There's no good reason to introduce the complexity of double NAT'ing.

Answer (score 1):

> I was thinking of connecting an ethernet cable from one of the LAN ports on ISP router to WAN port of my Archer C6. Would this work?

Yes, *if* your TP-Link Archer C6 is configured as an ***access point*** instead of a router.

> I would like to know how to configure C6 in order to achieve this?

Refer to the chapter in your user manual on how to "Configure the Router in Access Point Mode".

```
In Access Point mode, the device can be connected to a wired network and transform 
the wired access into wireless one to extend the wireless coverage of your existing 
network. Advanced functions like NAT, Parental Controls and QoS are not supported in 
this mode.  

 ...  
 
 4. Go to `Advanced > Operation Mode`, select `Access Point` and click `Save`.
```

Also turn off the radios in the ISP unit to avoid problems.

Comment: Excellent! Let me give this a try!